# How can I set an Android Makefile to copy/rename files?

Tags: android, build-process, makefile, gnu-make

According to the Android online docs there's currently no way to specify multiple/mixed file extensions for the gcc compiler in an Android makefile. The source I'm using, a public project, has multiple extensions and in order to get it to compile I need to rename the files with the other extensions .cpp before build.

I set up a project subfolder I can copy these files into and rename them and then just link to them from there but I'd like to make this step a part of the build process so that any time those files are modified I can be certain this build will reflect those changes.

I'm not sure how to tell the Android.mk file to copy the files and rename them. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
cp '$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SOURCE_ROOT)/Sprite.mm' '$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(MM_RENAMES)/Sprite.cpp'
```

I receive the following error:

> Anhdroid.mk:10 *** missing separator. Stop.

Thanks,

**Update**

Alternatively, if someone knows a way to embed a call to execute a shell/Perl script in the beginning of the makefile would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it, this worked to copy files:

```
$(shell cp -fr $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SOURCE_ROOT)/Sprite.mm $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(MM_RENAMES)/Sprite.cpp)
```

And this also works to run an outside script:

```
$(perl scripts/foo.pl)
```