# NDK: Compile c++ files with .mm extension

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk, g++

I have some C++ source files (with .mm extension) in an XCode project.
I'm trying to compile only those that are pure C++ (no objc syntax or cocoa runtime used) and compile them in an Android NDK build (NDK r8d).
The problem seems to be that g++ will not even consider .mm files as C++ and will fail with:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: Objective-C++ compiler not installed on this system
```

I tried:
1. LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .mm (in Android.mk) - doesn't help.
2. Search g++ documentation on how to accept custom file extensions - couldn't find any.

I'd really like to find a way to force NDK/g++ to accept .mm files, but open to other ideas like:

1. copy & rename .mm to .cpp for the Android project - I don't like this since it complicates the build and version control, but it seems like the most basic thing that could work.
2. build this as a static lib (using xcode) - I tried going there, but I wasn't sure which architecture to build for, or if it even makes sense.
3. Others?

Does anyone have some experience or ideas on this? Thanks.

**Solution (see accepted answer)**
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -x c++

Comment: You'll need to change (port) the `.mm` files to pure C++ and use the file extension `.cpp` or whichever one you prefer.

Comment: the ndk does not support .m or .mm extensions. You can try with ndk provided by cristax

Comment: thank you for the quick comments. @trojanfoe: I'm including this for an extension of your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327383/how-can-i-set-an-android-makefile-to-copy-rename-files

Comment: @blackbelt: right, I forgot to mention I considered that, but at least for now I'd rather stick with 'stock' NDK. Do you have experience with Crystax?

Comment: I used it for a while. Now I am working with the stock ndk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the ["-x c++" option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) to $CFLAGS variable in .mk file. This should force GCC to use the C++ compiler.

EDIT: sorry for the typo, "-x" option, not "-c" and "c++", not "cpp"

Comment: It's not just a case of forcing the compiler to accept the file, given it won't understand the Objective-C within the source file.  This can only be solved by manual intervention.

Comment: The OP states the problem clearly: he has a syntactically-pure C++ file named as an .mm-file and couldn't find an option for the GCC to treat  such files as C++ source.

Comment: That is true; I misread that he wanted to compile all his `.mm` files as C++ and only those with pure C++ were succeeding.

Comment: I'll test this flag soon, but to clarify - the pure c++ files with .mm extension aren't even being considered by the NDK g++ compiler currently, so none are succeeding so far.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the accepted answer, I'd still say that renaming the files to .CPP would be the right thing to do. What's so controversial about making the extension match the content? Xcode would be fine with compiling C++ files, and as a bonus, it'll protect you from accidentally polluting it with Objective C++ on the iOS side.

Comment: Or just compile them with the ObjC compiler.

Comment: ObjC (as opposed to ObjC++) won't compile C++ files.

Comment: It's certainly a good answer and design if you control the shared codebase. In my case I just couldn't modify it so I needed a way to make it work with that limitation. Plus, I was curious about the compiler flags since I remembered seeing something like that work.